# How do I initialize test data to mock context using C#, MOQ and XUnit?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have this setup in C# .NET Core 3.1.

```
public class IngestServiceTest
{
    private Mock<IDowJonesContext> mockDowJonesContext;
    private ILogger<object> _logger;
    private readonly IngestService ingestService;

    public IngestServiceTest()
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json").Build();
        _logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()).CreateLogger<object>();

        mockDowJonesContext = new Mock<IDowJonesContext>();
        ingestService = new IngestService(mockDowJonesContext.Object, configuration, _logger);
    }

    [Fact]
    private void SetupMockData()
    {
        var data = TestData.MockFileProcessLogs();
        mockDowJonesContext.Object.FileProcessLogs.AddRange(data);
        mockDowJonesContext.Object.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But at  `mockDowJonesContext.Object.FileProcessLogs.AddRange(data);`, it hits error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I have checked. `data` has 3 row count.

Comment: `FileProcessLogs` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you normally use a mock. Calling a method or property on the `Object` property of a mock is in most cases wrong, because that is a direct call on the mock itself and does not add any value to the test. What you want is probably something like:

```cs
    [Fact]
    private void SetupMockData()
    {
        var data = TestData.MockFileProcessLogs();
        mockDowJonesContext.Setup(x => x.FileProcessLogs).Returns(data);
        mockDowJonesContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges());
        // and then:
        ingestService.DoSomeProcessing();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Now my `data` got error. It says can't convert list to Dbset. So my data also has to be Dbset? is it `var data = new Mock<DbSet<FileProcessLog>>();`?

Comment: Your code snippet didn't say what types these where. It depends. It can be either the above or just `DbSet<FileProcessLog>`. Because it's data, you normally don't need to mock that.